# how to render dashboard widgets conditionaly in wordpress admin

Tags: plugins, dashboard

I would like to render some custom dashboard widget conditionally. If logined user have more than or equal to editor role I would like to render some more widgets than a user with subscriber role. How to do this?
Any help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// PHP 5.3 syntax - anonymous functions (Closures)
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', function(){
    if(current_user_can('activate_plugins')){ // Administrator
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('dbwidget-Administrator', '#Administrator', function(){
            // Print widget here
        });
    }elseif(current_user_can('delete_others_posts')){ // Editor
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('dbwidget-Editor', '#Editor', function(){
            // Print widget here
        });
    }elseif(current_user_can('delete_published_posts')){ // Author
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('dbwidget-Author', '#Author', function(){
            // Print widget here
        });
    }elseif(current_user_can('edit_posts')){ // Contributor
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('dbwidget-Contributor', '#Contributor', function(){
            // Print widget here
        });
    }elseif(current_user_can('read')){ // Subscriber
        wp_add_dashboard_widget('dbwidget-Subscriber', '#Subscriber', function(){
            // Print widget here
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see I chained them with elseif to ensure smooth Role degradation as Admin can do all the below too. Play with it as you wish. Learn more about [Roles and Capabilities here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).